# I would like to present the completion progress in percentage of each feature

Tags: azure

Similar to the Progress by user story calculation that can pull in the backlog, I am looking to see if there is a way for me to have this calculation under a custom field for each feature?

I couldn't find a way to add some kind of a formula to a custom field.

Comment: Hello @ssr, and welcom to SO. Please have a look here before asking a question -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . There is no way for us to provide useful feedback based on what you ask